# What to do when I have insignificant results in one-way MANOVA?

Tags: statistical-significance, manova

I am currently in a blind fury attempting to write up a dissertation on the effects of positive and negative coaching on the performance of Rocket League players.

As far as I can gather, a one way MANOVA was in order as I have:

IV : coaching style (none, positive, negative)
DV : performance metrics (Goal Difference, Saves, Shot Difference, Shot Percentage, Aggression)

All of the data is normally distributed and skewness and kurtosis is all good etc, but results came back at sig values of 0.303 and above, so clearly insignificant.

My questions are thus: did I do something wrong? If so what, if not, should I just write up 10k words on how I can't design a study correctly?

---------EDIT---------

Someone asked for my output stuff so I have attached a pdf of all my stuff [pdf :)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-X3njnXUhhnYsWhAxMWJN8dGy_pV5e_9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you can spend a chapter on the issues affecting the power of a study and a chapter on the issues that might have robbed your study of power then your thesis should be well received. Don't forget the possibility that the coaching styles do not make a difference.

Comment: Ok i get you, think i'm just frustrated to be honest but cant change the data! i appreciate you trying to help though :)

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to all if you could provide more information about your data, most importantly the output of your analysis, in order to further assist in answering your question.